# Why C:\Windows\addins\FXSEXT.ecf accessed by Jenkins git plugin

Tags: jenkins

The issue possibly is Jenkins-specific, but I suspect it might be a more general Java on Windows issue.

I configured a Windows Jenkins slave via JNLP agent on a new machine. When I tried to run a job, that is known to run fine on Windows slaves before I got the exception below. I could see in ProcMon that java.exe process tries to obtain Delete permissions to C:\Windows\addins\FXSEXT.ecf.

Why does it need that?

```
Building remotely on ccnet-2013 (6.3 windows-6.3 windows amd64-windows-6.3 amd64-windows amd64) in workspace /windows
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository <my repo path>
ERROR: Failed to clean the workspace
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: \windows\addins\FXSEXT.ecf
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:247)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:310)
    at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:212)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:301)
    at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:212)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:458)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:152)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:325)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'{code}
```

Comment: It seems to want to delete a protected file (http://manjolinjo.blogspot.com/2013/05/taking-of-filesfolders-protected-by.html). Maybe some setting around email notification?

Comment: The problem isn't related to `C:\Windows\addins\FXSEXT.ecf.`. Jenkins is trying to delete the whole Windows folder. That just happens to be the first file (in alphabetical order).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Jenkins is trying to delete the workspace/git repository, and for some reason, it's trying to wipe the file in the `\windows` folder. That suggests your git repository is misconfigured somewhere and it's trying to delete the wrong thing.

Comment: I can confirm there's no addins\FXSEXT.ecf file in my repository. Any suggestions what exactly is wrong with git repository. This is brand-new slave so it is supposed to grab a fresh clone from the remote repo. .